# FragmentStatePagerAdapter not removing fragments if parent fragment removed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am facing memory leak because some fragments are not removed. I have Activity that populates view with Fragment F1. This fragment has ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter associated with it. Adapter is feeling pager with another Fragment F2. Problem starts when in Activity I remove Fragment F1. Existing Fragments F2 are not removed.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is the same problem, but some time ago I had a problem with viewpager where the fragment lifecycle methods were never called and the problem was with the fragment manager.

So, when you create the adapter try passing childFragmentManager instead of supportFragmentManager and see if it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. Try to move your fragment F1 back into an activity. That might helps you determine if the problem is to have a fragment in a fragment. Android doesn't really like that. If I find something on my side, I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue here. After researching for a long time about how to correct it in a "right" way I couldn't get it working. So I was forced to explicit release all `F2`s fragments before removing the `F1` parent fragment (with a fragment transaction) from my activity.

```
// Remove all content from the FragmentStatePagerAdapter instance.
myAdapter.Content.Clear (); // Content here may be an ArrayList in Java or a List in C#.
myAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();

// Reset current empty adapter inside the ViewPager (this will make all existing F2 fragments to be released).
myViewPager.Adapter = myAdapter;

// Do the transaction removing the parent F1 fragment from the main Activity.
FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ()...
```

By following these steps, all `F2` fragments started being released form memory and they are also having their `OnPause`, `OnDestroyView` ... `OnDestroy` callbacks being invoked as well.